# Change button's background image from constructor of MainPage class

Tags: silverlight, xna

The code below code is throwing a `NullReferenceException`. I want to keep the button's background relative to the state of toggle button.

```
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
   {

    public static int key;
    public MainPage()
    {

        ImageBrush brush= new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/Music on.png", UriKind.Relative));
        if (key == 0)
            music.Background = brush;  //////NullReferenceException is throwing here
        else
            music.Background = null;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: where do you initialize `music`? Have you made sure that's not throwing the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `InitializeComponent()` method call in your constructor to be the first line of the constructor. The `InitializeComponent()` method is responsible for creation of your constituent controls on your page. Since you are currently calling it last, your music field is null causing the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: i have one more problem... UI of my games main page. when i pressing button it shows white rectangle(white flash) as a foreground...i dnt want this rectangle to be displayed ..how to solve this problem??